# Office 2013 KMS with KMS host on same computer

Tags: windows, windows-7, licensing, kms, microsoft-office-2013

Well, initially I wanted to run my KMS Host on Windows Server 2008 (non R2),but the KMS host version for Office 2013 is incompatible...

I finally relented and installed the KMS Host on Windows 7 (my workstation).  I've got 6 machines going with Office 2013 right now, 5 are activated fine.

The problem is, my copy of Office 2013 will not activate.  It claims it cannot find the KMS host (which again, is my own computer).  Has anyone seen any issues were Office wont activate if the KMS Host is 'local' to it?

## nslookup -type=srv _vlmcs._tcp

```
Server:  leela.domain.local
Address:  10.0.0.8

_vlmcs._tcp.domain.local SRV service location:
      priority       = 0
      weight         = 0
      port           = 1688
      svr hostname   = me.domain.local
me.domain.local        internet address = 10.0.0.52
```

## ospp.vbs /dstatus:

```
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---OOB_GRACE---
ERROR CODE: 0x4004F00C
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service
reported that the application is running within the valid grace period.
REMAINING GRACE: 29 days  (42918 minute(s) before expiring)
Last 5 characters of installed product key: XXXXX
DNS auto-discovery: KMS name not available
    Activation Interval: 120 minutes
    Renewal Interval: 10080 minutes
    KMS host caching: Enabled
```

## ospp.vbs /act:

```
Installed product key detected - attempting to activate the following product:
SKU ID: b322da9c-a2e2-4058-9e4e-f59a6970bd69
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Last 5 characters of installed product key: XXXXX
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F074
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product could not be activated.
No Key Management Service (KMS) could be contacted. Please see the Application Event Log for additional information.
To view the activation event history run: cscript OSPP.VBS /dhistorykms
```

## Status from another machine that does activate:

```
SKU ID: b322da9c-a2e2-4058-9e4e-f59a6970bd69
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED---
REMAINING GRACE: 179 days  (259115 minute(s) before expiring)
Last 5 characters of installed product key: XXXXX
    KMS machine name from DNS: me.domain.local:1688
    Activation Interval: 120 minutes
    Renewal Interval: 10080 minutes
    KMS host caching: Enabled
```

## slmgr /dlv:

```
Name: Office 15, KMSHostVL edition

Description: Office 15, VOLUME_KMS channel

Activation ID: 2e28138a-847f-42bc-9752-61b03fff33cd

Application ID: 0ff1ce15-a989-479d-af46-f275c6370663

Extended PID: 55041-00206-235-289923-03-1033-7601.0000-3312013

Installation ID: 013111873566329473204262852091176285573691815114164576

Processor Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88342

Machine Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88343

Use License URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88345

Product Key Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88344

Partial Product Key: XXXXX

License Status: Licensed

Remaining Windows rearm count: 1

Trusted time: 11/27/2013 2:27:46 PM



Key Management Service is enabled on this machine

Current count: 5

Listening on Port: 1688

DNS publishing enabled

KMS priority: Normal



Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients

Total requests received: 20

Failed requests received: 0

Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0

Requests with License Status Licensed: 1

Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 19

Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 0

Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0

Requests with License Status Notification: 0
```

The ONLY difference is that I am local to the KMS, where everyone else is just another client on the network.

Status of other items:

Firewall: OFF
Attempted: slmgr /skms 127.0.0.1:1688
Attempted: slmgr /ckms
**CAN** telnet to 1688 on my machine (the KMS host)
Attempted: ospp.vbs /sethst:foo.bar.local
ospp.vbs /dhistorykms comes back ***EMPTY***

Comment: I ended up spinning up a Win7 VM and adding that as a KMS host. Then everything activated honky dory. Go figure.

Comment: Did you check your local Firewall?